# Remove all references to ManagedObjects belonging to a ManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

I'm looking to integrate iCloud with a Core-Data-managed SQLite database (only on iOS 7 and later). I've been reading Apple's guide on using Core Data with iCloud (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG.pdf).

To quote from the guide, "Core Data posts an NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification notification. In your notification handler, you reset your managed object context and drop any references to existing managed objects."

Calling -reset on the MOC to reset it isn't the problem, the problem is the part where they say all references to managed objects need to be dropped. I understand why this needs to be done (because the persistent store is changing), what I don't know is how to do it.

All my Core Data work is handled by a singleton and I had originally thought of posting a notification, and listening classes could set all their managed objects to nil. First, this doesn't sound like a particularly good way of doing it. Secondly, I have a FetchedResultsController managing a tableView, the FetchedResultsController manages it's own managed objects, therefore, as far as I know, I can't set them to nil.

I'd be really grateful for any advice on what to do here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I handle situations like this is to post two notifications in my app: just before resetting, and just after resetting.

For example, I might post `MYMainContextWillResetNotification`, then reset the context, then post `MYMainContextDidResetNotification`.

Any controller receiving the will-reset notification should release its managed objects, but also store any information it will need to recover after the reset. Usually this will be one or more `NSManagedObjectID` objects. In some cases, you may not need to store anything, simply performing a fetch after the reset instead.

A typical method might look like this:

```
- (void)mainContextWillReset:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    self->noteID = note.objectID;
}
```

This code supposes there is a controller for a single note object. When the reset is about to take place, the note's object identifier is stored in an instance variable.

The did-reset notification method retrieves the note.

```
- (void)mainContextDidReset:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    note = [context existingObjectWithID:noteID error:NULL];
    [self refreshViews];
}
```

This code uses `existingObjectWithID:error:`, but you could equally do a fetch.

With an `NSFetchedResultsController`, you would need to call `performFetch:` in the did-reset method, to refresh the objects.

Comment: That's great Drew, thanks. A little off topic, but do you happen to know if there is a way to check if there is already a ubiquity store for the app in iCloud, before waiting for Core Data to come back with the new/existing ubiquity store?

Comment: I don't think there is a foolproof way. You can use metadata queries to see if there are transaction log files there, but it is no guarantee, because another device might just be slow uploading data.

Comment: Ah, OK. The model is based on there being only one 'User' object in the database, and the app's setup process involves the user entering info for the User object. How would you suggest dealing with the following scenario: The user has two devices, one with the app installed and iCloud enabled (which has, or is in the process of, uploaded data), and a another device as a fresh install of the app. If I continue with the User setup while CD does its thing with iCloud, the user has entered info that they didn't need to. In theory I could merge the data (?), but it doesn't make for a great UX.

Comment: I think deduping/merging is probably what you need to do. Another option might be to pass the username, or just a flag to indicate one exists, via the key value store.

Comment: Completely forgot about the key-value store, thanks. Just watched your Emsembles talk from NSConf (brilliant, by the way). By using Ensembles, does that mean there would be the PS I create (and pass to Ensembles), plus the Core Data-managed fallback store on the device?

Comment: Ensembles doesn't use the Core Data-iCloud sync at all. It is completely separate. You just have your PS. There is no fallback store, or changing between stores. Just the one store.

Comment: Great, working on integrating it now. Just got to figure out the deduping and merging. Thanks for all your help, really appreciate it.